# Producing subplots and then combine them into a figure later in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot

My program produces small figures during the command cycle. Is there a way to just save these figures and then combine them in one figure later?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Consider the code:

```
hFig = figure;

%# create temporary subplots as template
for i=1:2, h(i) = subplot(2,1,i); end       %# create subplots
pos = get(h, 'Position');                   %# record their positions
delete(h)                                   %# delete them

%# load the .fig files inside the new figure
fileNames = {'a.fig' 'b.fig'};              %# saved *.fig file names
for i=1:2
    %# load fig
    hFigFile = hgload( fileNames{i} );

    %# move/copy axis from old fig to new fig
    hAx = get(hFigFile, 'Child');           %# hAx = gca;
    set(hAx, 'Parent',hFig)
    %#hAx = copyobj(hAx,hFig);

    %# resize it to match subplot position
    set(hAx, 'Position',pos{i});

    %# delete old fig
    delete(hFigFile)
end
```

This was adapted from this [newsgroup discussion](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.soft-sys.matlab/browse_thread/thread/8ebd838156a5990b)

Comment: amazing, really really good. Thanks alot, this saves a lot of pain.

Comment: and the link to the newsgroup discussion is useful

Answer (score 1):

Use [`saveas`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/saveas.html). Save your subplot as a FIG file so you have complete control over it later (as opposed to a JPG).

Choose a tiling pattern and then use [`subplot`](http://matlab.izmiran.ru/help/techdoc/ref/subplot.html) to display multiple figures in one.

Comment: How do you load them then into a single figure?

Answer (score 1):

I have an answer here as an example:

```
h1 = figure(1)
plot(1:10,'o-r');
title('title');
xlabel('xlabel');
ylabel('ylabel');

% Copy contents
ch(1) = copyobj(gca,gcf);

% Figure 2
h2 = figure(2)
plot(1:30,'o-r');
title('title fig2');
xlabel('xlabel');
ylabel('ylabel');
% copy contents
ch(2) = copyobj(gca,gcf);

figure(3)
sh = subplot(1,2,1);
clear axes
p = get(sh,'position');
ah = copyobj(ch(1),gcf);
set(ah,'position',p);

% Create axis template
sh = subplot(1,2,2);
clear axes
p = get(sh,'position');
ah = copyobj(ch(2),gcf);
set(ah,'position',p);

% Delete template
% delete(sh);
```

Answer (score 1):

[Amro's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4010043/1714410) works greatly, but with boxplots you have to reset the Xtick and Xtick labels, otherwise, for some reason, they will not be resized according to the the subplot. When you create the boxplot or after opening the figure add:

```
set(gca,'XTick',<1d vector>,'XTickLabel',<1d cell vector>)
```

or put automatic ticks and labels

```
set(gca,'XTickMode','auto','XTickLabelMode','auto')
```

Comment: interesting, thanks for sharing. Did you try copying instead of moving axes (the commented line in my code)?. To be honest my solution is not without flaws; for example it would fail if the figures had different colormaps (unless you take the [extra effort](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-GNRWEH/index.html) to work around that)