# How can I move several existing plots to one subplot in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, plot

I have a function, `myFunkyFigure`, that takes in data, does some funky things, and returns an axis object for the figure it produces.

I would like to be able to invoke this function twice, creating two different figures:

```
fig(1) = myFunkyFigure(dataSet1);
fig(2) = myFunkyFigure(dataSet2);
```

Then I would like to put them into a subplot together.

Note that, because of the funkiness of `myFunkyFigure`, the following does not work.

```
subplot(2,1,1);
myFunkyFigure(dataSet1);
subplot(2,1,2);
myFunkyFigure(dataSet2);
```

I believe that I need something along the lines of `copyobj`, but I haven't been able to get that to work (I tried following [a solution in Stack Overflow question *Producing subplots and then combine them into a figure later in MATLAB*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4008880) but to no avail).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Obviously, we don't know how "funky" your figures are, but it should be noted in such a case that the cleanest solution would be to modify the function `myFunkyFigure` such that it accepts [additional optional arguments](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/varargin.html), specifically the handle of an axes in which to place the plot it creates. Then you would use it like so:

```
hSub1 = subplot(2,1,1);         %# Create a subplot
myFunkyFigure(dataSet1,hSub1);  %# Add a funky plot to the subplot axes
hSub2 = subplot(2,1,2);         %# Create a second subplot
myFunkyFigure(dataSet2,hSub2);  %# Add a funky plot to the second subplot axes
```

The default behavior of `myFunkyFigure` (i.e. no additional arguments specified) would be to create its own figure and place the plot there.

However, to answer the question you asked, here's a way to accomplish this given that you are outputting the *axes handles* (not the *figure handles*) in the vector `fig` (**note:** this is basically [the same solution as the one given in the other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4008880/producing-subplots-to-then-combine-them-into-a-figure-later-matlab/4010043#4010043), but since you mention having trouble adapting it I thought I'd reformat it to better fit your specific situation):

```
hFigure = figure();                              %# Create a new figure
hTemp = subplot(2,1,1,'Parent',hFigure);         %# Create a temporary subplot
newPos = get(hTemp,'Position');                  %# Get its position
delete(hTemp);                                   %# Delete the subplot
set(fig(1),'Parent',hFigure,'Position',newPos);  %# Move axes to the new figure
                                                 %#   and modify its position
hTemp = subplot(2,1,2,'Parent',hFigure);         %# Make a new temporary subplot
%# ...repeat the above for fig(2)
```

The above will actually *move* the axes from the old figure to the new figure. If you want the axes object to appear in *both* figures, you can instead use the function [COPYOBJ](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/copyobj.html) like so:

```
hNew = copyobj(fig(1),hFigure);  %# Copy fig(1) to hFigure, making a new handle
set(hNew,'Position',newPos);     %# Modify its position
```

Also note that [SUBPLOT](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/subplot.html) is only used here to generate a position for the tiling of the axes. You could avoid the need to create and then delete subplots by specifying the positions yourself.

Comment: (There was a [late update](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5807834/how-can-i-move-several-existing-plots-to-one-subplot-in-matlab/11579650#11579650) )

Answer (score 2):

The code from gnovice didn't work for me.

It seemed that a figure couldn't be made the child of another figure. For example hNew = copyobj(fig(1),hFigure); gave the error

```
Error using copyobj
Object figure[1] can not be a child of parent
figure[1]
```

Instead, I had to make the axes children of the new figure. This is the function I came up with

```
function []= move_to_subplots(ax,a,b)
%     %
% Inputs:
%       inputname: 
% Outputs:
%       name:  description type units
%       saved data: (does this overwrite a statically named file?)
%       plots:
%
% Standard call:
%
%
% Written by C. Hogg Date 2012_06_01
%
% 
debugmode=0;

hFigure=figure();

if ~exist('a')
        a=ceil(sqrt(length(ax)));
end

if ~exist('b')
        b=1;
    end    

if a*b<length(ax)|~exist('a')|~exist('b')
    disp('Auto subplot sizing')

    b=ceil(length(ax)/a);
end

for i=1:length(ax)

hTemp = subplot(a,b,i,'Parent',hFigure);         %# Make a new temporary subplot
newPos = get(hTemp,'Position');                  %# Get its position
delete(hTemp);

hNew = copyobj(ax(i),hFigure);
set(hNew,'Position',newPos)
end

%% Debug. Break point here.
if debugmode==1; dbstop tic; tic; dbclear all;end

end
```

This seems to work for me.

Comment: I think this should really be a comment on the previous answer, but I can't do this yet.

Comment: I just realised that gnovice said that fig should contain aixs handles. I'm learning to read gradually.