# Matlab GUI: migrate a plot to a new window

Tags: user-interface, matlab, plot

I've encountered such a problem, and hope you guys could help me out here.

I have a plot in my GUI, contained multiple lines with different linspecs and a group of legends.
And I've made a context menu which should allow users to open the EXACTLY same plot(retaining all line settings, title, legends, and so forth) in a new window(default figure, where it is able to save/edit the figure).
However I couldn't find a simple way to migrate the plot, except re-run the plot commands which is quite complicated(plot different data, etc.)

So, I am looking for the solution in the following two ways:

1. is there a simple way to migrate the plot into new figure window?
2. or is it possible to save the plot directly with current interface?

For 2, I'd like to clarify that I only want to save the plot, not all GUI interface. I've tried `saveas(handle.Plot,...)` but it saved the GUI interface as an entity.

I hope the point has been made clear, thanks for your time. Cheers.

Comment: a related question: [producing subplots to then combine them into a figure later in MATLAB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4008880/producing-subplots-to-then-combine-them-into-a-figure-later-in-matlab)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this task you can probably use the builtin Matlab function  [`copyobj`](http://www.mathworks.fr/help/techdoc/ref/copyobj.html) which does exactly this (i.e. the first option mentionned in your question).

The following piece of code demonstrates its usage:

```
h1=figure;
a1=plot((1:100),rand(1,100),'r-');
hold on
plot((1:100),rand(1,100),'b+');
legend({'plot1';'plot2'});
h2=figure;
copyobj(get(h1,'children'),h2);
```

Hope it works as well in your case.

**UPDATE:** as far as I understand this, your second solution would involve the `saveas` function which unfortunately works with the figure environment and not with axes (as you experienced it). So a workaround would probably involve copying the desired axes to a new figure with the method given above and then use `saveas`.

Comment: thanks for the answer. Now I'm out of duty, so I'll try your answer tomorrow. It seems quite plausible. :D