# How can I instantiate one .fig file onto another in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, hierarchy, figure, matlab-guide

I have a `block.fig` file which encapsulates some block of my graphical user interface (GUI).
I want to create a `full.fig` file which uses many instances of that GUI encapsulated in `block.fig`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

It's not very clear from you question whether the following applies, but maybe you can adapt [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4008880/producing-subplots-to-then-combine-them-into-a-figure-later-in-matlab/4010043#4010043) to a similar question by picking the components (with [FINDOBJ](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/findobj.html)) from the loaded figure and copy/move them to the new figure.

A quick example:

```
%# create and save block.fig
plot(1:10)
uicontrol('style','text','string','hello')
hgsave('block.fig')
close all

%# create new figure, load saved .fig
hFig = hgload('block.fig');
h = figure;

%# copy the components you want (also think of using the 'Tag' property)
copyobj(findobj(hFig,'type','uicontrol'), h)

%# delete loaded .fig
delete(hFig)
```